# How many folders can I put in one Windows folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, windows-server, file-organization

I have a 10M folders. Each folder contains 13 files.

All these folders I would like to put in one main folder (root).

Is there any limitation in Windows Server for that?

Comment: Do you actually have 10,000,000 folders?  Questions are expected to be practical questions.

Comment: Path length is limited to 260 characters, so this will limit how many nested folders you can have.>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I have

Comment: I'm fascinated. Why do you need 10M folders of 13 files each?

Comment: I find that somewhere in the 100,000 **file or folder** range, directory access starts to slow down quite a bit. Make a hierarchy - 100 folders of 100 folders of 1,000 folders of 13 files and you'll have no problem at all. Or something similar. If the names are pseudo-random hexadecimal then just use the first 3 characters as one directory, the next three as another, the next 3 as another. Or something like that. But 10,000,000 (or even 1,000,000) in one directory? That's asking for some serious access time problems.

Comment: Although some defragment programs allow you to defragment the MFT at this level it would probably just lessen the pain and not eliminate it.

Comment: @PaddyLandau It's an obscure requirement but according to the comments in the code there is this one website that needs it in order to permit a certain question to be asked. Without it the question keeps getting closed and deleted.

Comment: Consider a database.  This is not the correct solution.

Comment: @PaddyLandau Large organizations (companies, nonprofits, research groups) oftentimes generate unusual situations like this due to poor information management practices. This one in particular sounds startlingly similar to what I've heard from a sysadmin at a large American company. No, I'm not going to name which one. OP probably has avoided naming theirs for the same reason - to avoid the potential for legal trouble with their company.

Comment: So you already have all these folders but organised in a different way? What is the problem with the current setup? I would understand the question if you was wondering if it would be feasible because you had some weird requirement that would lead to a situation like the one you describe but why on earth actively creating this situation from an existing working situation?

Comment: Unlike other people I can see some good reasons for many folders/files when access by a spalist program and never accessed by a user with windows explorer.   Use a file system makes the software more portable, enables the use of many different backup tools and caching remote file systems etc.   But only if files are never changed once added, and the software never needs to access a list of all files/folders.

Comment: I can't help thinking that if you even need to ask this, [you're doing it wrong](https://xkcd.com/463/)…

Comment: The proliferation of backseat drivers amuses me.  Let's assume the OP knows what they are doing, and just answer their question.  I have worked on several systems that were designed to work for 10 years (not Windows systems).  30 years later, they are still running, and they have literally trillions of files on them all stored in a flat system (no hierarchy at all).  No one ever imagined those systems would still be operating after 30 years, or designed them for such use.  Sometimes you just have to work with what you have, and don't have the luxury of redesigning everything from scratch.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/453348/is-it-bad-if-millions-of-files-are-stored-in-one-ntfs-folder

Comment: @PaddyLandau Have seen this kind of thing show up spontaneously when you have very specific information about things and the system is very old. Say you have a book catalog where each book ends up with 13 files representing it (front cover, back cover, blurb, price history, idk--somehow you end up with 13). Or even more likely, an order system where every order ends up with 13 files. Or a laboratory sample system where every sample ends up with 13 files. You started off with 100 things*13 files each and it worked fine...now you have 10 mil and still haven't rewritten it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As far the theoretical capacities of NTFS are concerned, there is no problem.

The Microsoft article on
[Maximum Sizes on an NTFS Volume](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc781134(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-sizes-on-an-ntfs-volume)
specifies that the maximum of files per volume is 4,294,967,295,
and that should also be the maximum on folders.
However, you would need an extremely fast computer with lots of RAM to be able
to even view that folder in Explorer.

From my own experience, on a good computer of several years ago, viewing a folder
with thousands of sub-folders took some dozen of seconds just to show the folder.
I have no idea what would happen with 10 million sub-folders, but surely you
would need a lot of patience even if the computer could handle it. Eventually.

I really suggest to rethink again your folder architecture.

Comment: In particular, even though NTFS stores data in a B+-tree (or B*-tree?), Windows only provides sequential mechanisms to list directories. So you probably want to assume linear searches will occur...

Comment: In practice insane amount of folders are usually in temp, cache, upload and other programmatically managed folders which are not intended to be viewed using Explorer. And usually the folder contents is never listed, the files are accessed using hashes or paths stored in a database.

Comment: Seconding the point about usability issues. This is a case where the OP probably wants a database, but if not they almost certainly _need_ to do directory hashing of some sort to generate a more deeply nested tree structure with a much lower fan-out at each level to make this even remotely usable.

Comment: If anyone's curious where  4,294,967,295 comes from, it's 2^32-1.

Comment: The OP never mentioned that he wanted to view the files on explorer.

Comment: @PedroLobito: Remember that he accepted this answer. Besides, the same slowdown would be felt by any program that opened such a folder (or even opened a sub-folder).

Comment: @harrymc "_the same slowdown would be felt by any program that opened such a folder_" - Are you sure the system uses the same resources when a folder's opened on explorer and programmatically on a shell/cmd ?

Comment: @PedroLobito: Any reference to a sub-folder will pass through all the folders in the path.

Comment: @harrymc You aren't answering my question, but that's perfectly fine. Good luck.

Comment: @user541686: Not quite. In Windows, wildcard expansion happens in the kernel and there's no reason it can't do abc* correctly on the BTree and not scan all the files but only the range.

Comment: @Joshua: Try getting the lexicographically last file in a directory with wildcards. Now how many programs do you think take such an approach, and why?

Answer (score 47):

This may be an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps what you are doing is better suited for a database rather than a filesystem. With a database, you can *easily* store and access many millions of records quickly and efficiently. The accepted answer is correct in saying NTFS is theoretically able to store this many records, but it won't be very fast. This is true for essentially all filesystems (e.g. NTFS, exFAT, ext4, HFS...). They simply aren't designed to be sufficiently scalable for what you're trying to do.

One of the main reasons for this is that most operating systems' filesystem API can only return the entire list of directory entries at once. There is no way to retrieve only directories that match a certain pattern in typical filesystems, for example. It would have to retrieve them *all* and *then* parse the (massive) output for the names you want. The same is true with other file/directory attributes in addition to name like size, creation and modification time, etc. This isn't the case with databases.

Comment: Small note - ext4 evolved from ext3 which evolved from ext2 which evolved from BFS/UFS which predates DOS. HFS similarly have evolution unrelated to DOS FAT.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Actually ext4 was entirely rewritten, whereas ext3 was just ext2 with a journal duct taped to it.

Comment: Even NTFS more closely derived from OS/2's HPFS than DOS FAT (though it was designed from scratch in any case, refer Helen Custer's *Inside the Windows NT File System* if you can find it anywhere.  I think exFAT might be the only system in that list that actually has origins in DOS.

Comment: @throx I meant the general filesystem concept that is often followed today, not that they're all derived from the same implementation. I've removed that sentence since it was poorly worded.

Comment: @forest I got that, but saying that the ideas originated in DOS is wildly off base.  DOS added directory structures in 1982, whereas MULTICS invented them a mere 13 years prior in 1969, which UNIX v1 through v7 and its various branches copied widely before DOS came anywhere near.  All of the file systems other than exFAT were derived from MULTICS through UNIX and VMS well prior to DOS.

Comment: @throx Ah, you're right: https://multicians.org/fjcc4.html. I suppose I (foolishly) didn't consider that to be a "real" filesystem because it's so foreign to me. :)

Comment: "filesystem API can only return the entire list of directory entries at once". Is that really true? The Win32 API allows you to only returns files of a specific pattern and also allow you to query one file after another (FindFirstFile/FindNextFile and so on). Which would seem to support the intended scenario just fine. I'd surprised if *Nix didn't have similar APIs. It's probably true that many applications would handle the situation badly though, but the APIs themselves seem to support the scenario.

Comment: @Voo: Acutally *n?x doesn't have such an API.

Comment: @Joshua You seem to be right on a quick glance: Linux (Posix really) only has `readdir` as a kernel interface and that doesn't seem to allow any wildcards/patterns.

Comment: @Voo so what about `getdents` that is used to read in batches?

Comment: @eis I'm far from an expert on the Linux kernel calls, I just looked through the POSIX standard and readdir didn't have any fitting options. `getdents` seems to be Linux specific but from reading the manpage I'm not sure how you'd use a wildcard to only get specific files out of the directory without having to linearly search through it? I might be completely wrong - I mean I honestly would expect such functionality to exist.

Comment: @Voo I didn't say it allows for wildcards or patterns, but I did say it allows to read in batches, so it doesn't have to return "the entire list of directory entries at once". Also, [it's not linux specific](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getdents&sektion=2) either.

Comment: ah, and I guess readdir allows that too, it will just return the entries one-by-one and not as a collection like getdents does.

Comment: @eis Sure batching improves things by a constant factor, but you'll still have to linearly go through all files to get at the one you're interested at. That's basically the same difference as using a hashmap instead of a list.

Comment: @Voo Are you sure those aren't just library functions and that the syscalls themselves actually support this? Anyway even if it is true that Windows has syscalls that can do that, it still doesn't provide the flexibility that a database does.

Comment: @forest The underlying nt call is NtQueryDirectoryFile which also takes an optional FileName parameter supporting wildcards. I don't think this is the place to argue about database design, but storing giant files in a db isn't universally considered a best practice either. It's reasonable to store simply meta data and access the files on disk - how much folder size would matter on this case I don't know though.

Comment: @Voo OK, that's interesting to know. That would make searches based on file name more efficient (although not for any other file attributes), assuming the filesystem driver implements it efficiently. (Also, OP is storing millions of small files, not giant files. I agree a db is not the place for truly massive entries.)

Answer (score 26):

The number of files inside a folder has **nothing to do with the OS**. It's a feature of the *file system* although the system you use may in turn has lower limitations. Some file systems limit the number of files in a folder but some others just limit the total number of files in a volume, and some don't have any limits at all. See [file systems' limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits). Note that basically a directory is just a file whose content is a list of other files

If you use [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT), the maximum number is **2 796 202 files per folder**. In [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) the limit is 2<sup>32</sup>-1 files per volume. And if you use [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) then the limit depends on the FAT version

- FAT12: 4 068 for 8 KiB clusters
- FAT16: 65 460 for 32 KiB clusters
- FAT32: 268 173 300 for 32 KiB clusters

Windows also natively support a few other file systems like ReFS, or you can install drivers for other non-native file systems. They may in turn have different limits

But in any case **having a huge number of files in a folder is a very bad idea**. The listing and operating speed depends on how the file system stores its metadata, for example in FAT it's a linear list so it's very slow. But even with an efficient way to list files like a B+tree in NTFS it's still slow. In general I avoid having more than 2000 files in a folder

The better solution in your case should be *some kind of database*. However if you *really* have to store the files directly in a drive then you need to **distribute the files evenly to multiple smaller folders**. The common way is to hash the file name or content and split into folders having part of that name. For example if the hash is `0xabcdef12` (32 bits) then store the file in `ab/cd/ef/12`, `ab/cde/f12` or `2af/0de/f12` (each path component represents 8/8/8/8, 8/12/12 and 10/10/12 bits of the original value respectively). This way no folder should have too many or too few files. See

- [How to spread/hash multiple files on disk without storing more than 1000 per directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12157836/995714)
- [Storing a million images in the filesystem](https://serverfault.com/q/95444/343888)
- [Accessing thousands of files in hash of directories](https://superuser.com/q/444286/241386)

This method is commonly used in git or docker

## See also

- [Is it bad if millions of files are stored in one NTFS folder?](https://superuser.com/q/453348/241386)
- [Performance implications of storing 600,000+ images in the same folder (NTFS)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2625545/995714)
- [Can file system performance decrease if there is a very large number of files in a single directory (NTFS)?](https://superuser.com/q/623965/241386)
- [Having 1 million folder or have 1 million files in one folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29555313/995714)
- [How many files can you put in a Windows folder without a noticable performance degradation?](https://superuser.com/q/6382/241386)
- [NTFS performance and large volumes of files and directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197162/995714)
- [How do you deal with lots of small files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115882/995714)
- [Millions of small graphics files and how to overcome slow file system access on XP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1638219/995714)
- [How many files in a directory is too many (on Windows and Linux)? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2994544/995714)
- [Millions of (small) text files in a folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/411091/44425)
- [Performance associated with storing millions of files on NTFS](https://serverfault.com/q/622872/343888)

Comment: Probably (I didn't DV, but the thought crossed my mind) because you have too much on the technical limits before getting to the "_But in any case..._" warning. It would be better (IMHO) to start with the "in practice, it's a bad idea" paragraph (and the possible remedies) and only then delve into the technical details). On the plus side, your "_The better way_" section is very helpful.

Comment: "The number of files inside a folder has nothing to do with the OS. It's a feature of the file system." – If the file system supports 100000 files but the OS requires each file to have a unique number and requires the type of that number to be a 16 bit integer, then there will be a OS-imposed limitations. Correct would be to say that the limits are the minimum of the filesystem limits, OS limits, and the limits of the tools you use to access the files. *Especially* on Windows, there are tons of weird limits that do not exist in NTFS, but exist in different APIs and in the Explorer.

Comment: In particular, there are several different APIs supported by Windows for backwards compatibility, and they may have different limits, and the tools the OP uses may use one or the other of those APIs.

Comment: I would strongly recommend trying to organise the files in some way that corresponds to one of the ways you might navigate or search through them. Just using a hash would be arbitrary and would only really provide a minor improvement, while also slowing down searching.

Comment: @NotThatGuy no one traverses through millions of files and folders manually. And even if you distribute the file to some other rules then some folders may have millions of files and others have only a few files which not an improvement at all. And as I said, a proper database is highly recommended

Comment: @JörgWMittag True, Win32 doesn't support all NTFS features. I've corrected that

Comment: @phuclv If you're not ever going to manually traverse them, why should you split them into multiple directories in the first place (apart from file system restrictions)? Why would it be a problem that listing them takes long? Usually this is something you do when you manually traverse them. Or maybe when you're looking for a specific one, but how would directories help you there?

Comment: @NotThatGuy "traversing" in the comment means going into subfolders manually. Only in that case you care about the meanings of the folder names. Automation code never cares about that so a hash is sufficient and better. Besides having a too big folder is also slower to look for a specific file by the automation code